# Replace or update entries in Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm trying to cleanse some data ('phone numbers in this example) in an Excel (.xlsx) file on upload. I have the following code to open the file:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        try
        {
            string filePath = ("confirm//") + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = 
                new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            Workbook wb = 
                xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath(filePath));

            wb.Activate();
            string csvPath = (filePath.Replace(".xlsx", ".csv"));

            wb.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(csvPath), 
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);

            wb.Close();             

            // call method to parse csv
            ReadRec(csvPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {//}
    else
    {//}
}
```

Then something like this to add a zero to the start of the number if not already there:

```
private void ReadRec(string csvName)
{
    StreamReader Sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(csvName));
    string s;

    while (!Sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        s = Sr.ReadLine();

        string company = s.Split(',')[0];
        string phone = s.Split(',')[1];
        string NAME = s.Split(',')[2];

        if (!phone.StartsWith("0"))
        {
            phone = "0" + phone;
        }
    }
    Sr.Close();
}
```

This seems to work well but what I haven't been able to figure out is how to re-insert the updated numbers back into the spreadsheet (or create a new Excel file with the updated data).

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: How big is this file? It is really problematic to read and write on the same file. Could you load everything in memory?

Comment: Can you write to excel??

Comment: It's pretty big - about 10,000 rows long.

Comment: @Kyle: you mean write the data into a new file? That would be fine but I'm unsure of how to do that either.

Comment: Just to warn you, Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of the Excel application in a server environment like ASP.NET, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: It's only going to be used on the localhost.

Comment: @Robert May be you can use Microsoft.office.interop.excel

Comment: If you want the output to be xls(x) then do the manipulation on the excel file instead of converting it to CSV first.

Comment: @NickSlash: Thanks. Any pointers on how I'd go about manipulating the excel file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally cobbled together a solution that sort of works (well enough for my current purposes) but is far from ideal:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        try
        {
            var excelApp = new Application();
            excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\myFile.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                                   Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            var ws = excelApp.Worksheets;
            var worksheet = (Worksheet)ws.get_Item("Sheet1");
            Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
            object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;

            for (int row = 1; row <= values.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
            {
                string phone = Convert.ToString(values[row, 2]);
                if (!phone.StartsWith("0"))
                {
                    phone = "0" + phone;
                }
                range.Cells.set_Item(row, 2, phone);
            }
            excelApp.Save("C:\\Leads.xls");
            excelApp.Quit();
       }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {//}
    else
    {//}
}
```

-EDIT- In order for this to work, I had to open the `.xlsx` file in Excel and save it as `.xls`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) or [asp.net](/questions/tagged/asp.net) so this (probably) wont be working code.

Interop in C# *should* be really simple, the documentation usually has examples specific to C# so if this fails, take a look at the MSDN.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        try
        {
            string filePath = ("confirm//") + FileUpload1.FileName;
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = 
                new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            Workbook wb = 
                xl.Application.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath(filePath));

            wb.Activate();

            Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets(1); // use the first sheet 1-based index i think

            for (long row = 2; i <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count; i++) {
                // assume row 1 is a title so start at row 2
                // ws.Cells(row, 1) // company
                // ws.Cells(row, 2) // phone
                // ws.Cells(row, 3) // name
                if (!ws.Cells(row,2).Value2.StartsWith("0") {
                    ws.Cells(row,2).Value2 = "0" + ws.Cells(row,2).Value2
                }
            }

            //string csvPath = (filePath.Replace(".xlsx", ".csv"));

            //wb.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(csvPath), 
            //    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
            wb.Save(); // as were directly modifying the file, no need to save elsewhere

            wb.Close();             

            // call method to parse csv
            //ReadRec(csvPath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {//}
    else
    {//}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm having difficulty retrieving the contents of the cells.
I tried `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();` but it throws an `object does not contain definition for value` error.

Comment: @LucaZiegler your not wrong. I did also mention it probably wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have using this code for UPDATE the data in the EXCEL sheet

```
 try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET ID=@value,Name=@value2,Age=@value3 where ID=@value4";
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", txtid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", txtname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", txtage.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", txtupdate.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully");
            cn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + e3);
        }
```

Comment: What is cmd?  What is cn? It's not very helpful to only have part of the solution!